# giving random name to a file using php

Tags: javascript, php

i am trying to give random name to my file name using this code but how do i provide file path and name so it works?

this is my file path

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/file.js"></script>
```

and here's my code

```
<?php
function random_string($length) {
    $key = '';
    $keys = array_merge(range(0, 9), range('a', 'z'));

    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $key .= $keys[array_rand($keys)];
    }

    return $key;
}

echo random_string(50);
?>
```

this out put wil be like this " i40q6jjmvib6tb36skrutcitok1gxfkprz65e50xsiembjov0b "

and i want it to be like this on my file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/i40q6jjmvib6tb36skrutcitok1gxfkprz65e50xsiembjov0b.js"></script>
```

Comment: what is purpose of doing like this ?

Comment: @Rishi the prpose is to generate uniqe file name only

Comment: You will get `file not found` error, if file with that name is not found.

Comment: @Rishi any sulotion ? what i am thinking is to put my file.js in a folder alone and get that js file to the page with generated name

Comment: If you want to hide some sensitive code from user end you should use server side like php. it meaning less to change file name still it will be easily accessible by other.

Comment: @Rishi i know but my main pupose is to hide file ad from adblocker, i know ad blocker add the code or file to their updated list and what i am trying to do is to give random name to file

Comment: @Rishi i have no problem updating code in that file by myself but i want the file to have unique name instead of i change it every time

Comment: So where you are getting `random_string` you can rename js file name first and then use in `src` in script tag.

Comment: @Rishi how i don't get it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
function random_string($length) {
    $key = '';
    $keys = array_merge(range(0, 9), range('a', 'z'));

    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $key .= $keys[array_rand($keys)];
    }

    return "js-".$key.".js"; // Change here
}

echo random_string(50);
?>
```

And in your `htaccess`, write condition for rewriting 
`/js\-[a-z0-9]*\.js/` to `file.js`

Comment: Dear check my question here and answer if you can http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42212460/edit-code-my-breadcrumbs-using-php

Comment: there is no option to mark bro i wanted to mark it. how do i do it there is no mark option ?

Comment: and it looks like page deleted you see it says page not found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42212460/edit-code-my-breadcrumbs-using-php

Comment: and i need answer here too my friend if you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42229136/getting-file-name-without-file-extention-in-my-php-code

Comment: sorry bro. I can't understand the question clearly. Please explain it @MmPp . also if you would like to join a whatsapp group for programmers, whatsapp to +91-8590237893

Comment: i will join my friend thanks for invite... my question was on that link is i want to grab file name here 'HERE I MUST GET CURRENT FILE NAME' => 'This Shirt'

Comment: like this <?php echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?> it will get file name but i want something like that to grab file name here 'this-shirt' => 'This Shirt' on " this-shirt " is place

Comment: that is if the filename is get-data.php you want to take Get Data  . right?

Comment: no bro. look here " 'this-shirt' => 'This Shirt' " this is file here " this-shirt " it's with full extention it's " this-shirt.php " there i want php to grab file name there

Comment: i am not clear. If the current filename is "get-data.php" , you want to get "Get Data". ?

Comment: yes bro but look here 'get-data' => 'This Shirt' or 'this-shirt' => 'This Shirt' or 'this-file' => 'This Shirt' or 'file-name' => 'This Shirt' those page names like get-data.php , this-shirt.php , this-file.php , file-name.php

Comment: so i want 'HERE' => 'This Shirt' it must get file name by itself on any page i place this whole php code

Comment: here another example bro, the page that i place the code is my-file.php and on that area here 'this-shirt' => 'This Shirt' i must get like this 'my-file' => 'This Shirt'

Comment: so my point is to get file name only on that area using php code instead i put file name manually on every page i create

Comment: can ou help me with this dear http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42262290/need-help-in-my-php-code-getting-wrong-directory-on-breadcrumb

Comment: completed. Check it.

Comment: dear did you get my replay on comments on your answer on last page

Comment: and only 1 problem i am facing now. it's showing like this on output `<a href="http://domain.com">Home</a> &raquo; <a href="//Folder/">Folder</a> &raquo; <a href="//Folder/Folder/"></a> Live TV </div>` there more / added

Comment: you can see 2 lines `"/".$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];`. <br />I added it for testing purpose. try removing it and check whether the problem is solved or if not, comment here

Comment: dear sagar some how i am not able to post questions here right now and i need your help on small thing on php code you made for me i have made my question and code on plnkr code here . please help me with it if you can https://plnkr.co/edit/oNG4jnDM6yXR6kttyab1?p=catalogue

Comment: i can't get the question. Please explain here (or) create an account and post it .

Comment: dear sagar can you please check my question here and answer if you can http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42379499/trying-to-post-only-one-single-culomn-into-database

Answer (score 1):

First rename your `file.js` file

```
$random_name = random_string(50);
$dir    = '/your_path/';
$files = scandir($dir, 1);
rename($dir."/".$files[0], $dir."/".$random_name);
```

And then use this random name in html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/<?php echo $random_name;?>"></script>
```

Above both code should be in same .php file

Comment: i have add my file.js into xjs folder and it's on root directory so i don't have to add dots and i used the code like this this and it takes out whole things on my page 

<?php
$random_name = random_string(50);
$dir    = '/xjs/';
$files = scandir($dir, 1);
rename($dir."/".$files[0], $dir."/".$random_name);
?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/xjs/<?php echo $random_name;?>"></script>

Comment: and yes i have changed it's name too

Comment: each time renaming the file make high time complexity. Don't go for it ever.

Comment: Thanks for the appreciation.