# getting file name without file extention in my php code

Tags: php, filenames

what i'm trying to do here, in my php code below i have to set file name manually and i want to make it some how it grabds the file name automatically but without file extention

here's part of my code where i want to get file name

```
$Pages = array(
    'clothes' => 'Clothes',
    'shirt' => 'shirt',
    'this-shirt' => 'This Shirt'
);
```

where it says "this-shirt" is file name and i want it to be set automatically instead of i write it down everytime i create a page. also here's full code

```
<?php
$Pages = array(
    'clothes' => 'Clothes',
    'shirt' => 'shirt',
    'this-shirt' => 'This Shirt'
);

$path = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
$parts = explode('/', $path);
if (count($parts) < 2) {
    echo("home");
} else {
    echo ("<a href=\"http://domain.com\">Home</a> &raquo; ");
    for ($i = 2; $i < count($parts); $i++) {
        if (!strstr($parts[$i], ".")) {
            echo("<a href=\"");
            for ($j = 0; $j <= $i; $j++) {
                echo $parts[$j] . "/";
            };
            echo("\">" . str_replace('-', ' ', $Pages[$parts[$i]]) . "</a> &raquo; ");
        } else {
            $str = $parts[$i];
            $pos = strrpos($str, ".");
            $parts[$i] = substr($str, 0, $pos);
            echo str_replace('-', ' ', $Pages[$parts[$i]]);
        }
    }
}
```

hope you get the idea. thanks

Comment: `$file = 'this-shirt.pdf'; $filename = (count(explode('.', $file)) === 1 ? $file : implode('.', array_slice(explode('.', $file), 0, (count(explode('.', $file))-1)))); echo $filename;`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus dear can you please post your code on answer? because it is not clear like this

Comment: Which variable contains `this-shirt` **with** the extension?

Comment: this-shirt is file name like this this-shirt.php but everytime i put this whole code on a page i created i have to change it to the current page name. instead of that all i want php grab the file name by itself there. i don't want to create for example file with name my-file.php and place that whole code on that page and change this-shirt to my-file

Comment: I see. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
// get this-shirt.php from the URL
$file = basename($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);

// pure magic
$filename = (count(explode('.', $file)) === 1 ? $file : implode('.', array_slice(explode('.', $file), 0, (count(explode('.', $file))-1))));

$Pages = array(
    'clothes' => 'Clothes',
    'shirt' => 'shirt',
    $filename => 'This Shirt' // use $filename to declare the array's key
);
```

Comment: worked bro. exactly like i wanted. thank you so much

Comment: dear can you hhelp me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42262290/need-help-in-my-php-code-getting-wrong-directory-on-breadcrumb