# need help in my php code getting wrong directory on breadcrumb

Tags: php

my php breadcrumb code is below and the problem is, this is my directory

http://domain.com/folder

using the code below i get directory like this

`Home » » Folder` instead of `Home » Folder`

i don't know what is wrong in the code

```
<?php
    $file = basename($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);

    $filename = (count(explode('.', $file)) === 1 ? $file : implode('.', array_slice(explode('.', $file), 0, (count(explode('.', $file))-1))));

    $Pages = array(
        $filename => 'Folder'
    );

    $path = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
    $parts = explode('/',$path);
    if (count($parts) < 2)
    {
    echo("home");
    }
    else
    {
    echo ("<a href=\"http://domain.com\">Home</a> &raquo; ");
    for ($i = 1; $i < count($parts); $i++)
        {
        if (!strstr($parts[$i],"."))
            {
            echo("<a href=\"");
            for ($j = 0; $j <= $i; $j++) {echo $parts[$j]."/";};
            echo("\">". str_replace('-', ' ', $Pages[$parts[$i]])."</a> &raquo; ");
            }
        else
            {
            $str = $parts[$i];
            $pos = strrpos($str,".");
            $parts[$i] = substr($str, 0, $pos);
            echo str_replace('-', ' ', $Pages[$parts[$i]]);
            };
        };
    };  
?>
```

Here's my second code

```
<?php
    $file = basename("/".$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);

    $filename = (count(explode('.', $file)) === 1 ? $file : implode('.', array_slice(explode('.', $file), 0, (count(explode('.', $file))-1))));
    $Pages = array(
        'folder' => 'Folder',
        $filename => 'Folder'
    );

    $path = "/".$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
    $parts = explode('/',$path);
    if (count($parts) < 2)
    {
    echo("home");
    }
    else
    {
    echo ("<a href=\"http://domain.com\">Home</a>  ");
    $cnt = count($parts);
    for ($i = 2; $i < $cnt; $i++)
        {
        if (!strstr($parts[$i],"."))
            {
            echo("&raquo; <a href=\"");
            for ($j = 0; $j <= $i; $j++) {echo $parts[$j]."/";};
            echo("\">". str_replace('-', ' ', $Pages[$parts[$i]])."</a> ");
            }
        else
            {
            $str = $parts[$i];
            $pos = strrpos($str,".");
            $parts[$i] = substr($str, 0, $pos);
            echo str_replace('-', ' ', $Pages[$parts[$i]]);
            };
        };
    };  
?>
```

Comment: *"fix my php code"* - Sounds like a direct order.

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorry it's not an order

Comment: there's no javascript (or jQuery, obviously) in the code - please don't tag spam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start the `for` loop which uses `$i` as index with initial value 2 instead of 1.

```js
<?php
    $file = basename("/".$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);

    $filename = (count(explode('.', $file)) === 1 ? $file : implode('.', array_slice(explode('.', $file), 0, (count(explode('.', $file))-1))));
    $Pages = array(
        $filename => 'Folder'
    );

    $path = "/".$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
    $parts = explode('/',$path);
    if (count($parts) < 2)
    {
    echo("home");
    }
    else
    {
    echo ("<a href=\"http://domain.com\">Home</a>  ");
    $cnt = count($parts);
    for ($i = 1; $i < $cnt; $i++)
        {
        if (!strstr($parts[$i],"."))
            {
            echo("&raquo; <a href=\"");
            for ($j = 0; $j <= $i; $j++) {echo $parts[$j]."/";};
            echo("\">". str_replace('-', ' ', $Pages[$parts[$i]])."</a> ");
            }
        else
            {
            $str = $parts[$i];
            $pos = strrpos($str,".");
            $parts[$i] = substr($str, 0, $pos);
            echo str_replace('-', ' ', $Pages[$parts[$i]]);
            };
        };
    };  
?>
```

Comment: thanks a lot dear that worked but how i use it in this directory http://domain.com/folder/folder it doesn't work if i put 2 or 1 either i get like this `Home » »` Folder or like this `Home » Folder » » Folder` and on pages array i am using it like this 

`$Pages = array(
        'folder' => 'Folder',
        $filename => 'Folder'
    );`

Comment: thanks for your hard work that worked. but what have you changed on your last edit ?

Comment: `&raquo;` shifted to loop body