# Trying to post only one single column into database

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my code that inserts data into a database table, but I want grab data and display it inside those div below:

```
<?php
// only proccss the form if $_POST isn't empty
if ( ! empty( $_POST ) ) {

// connect to MySQL
$mysqli = new mysqli( 'localhost', 'root', '', 'mydb' );

// Check our connection
if ( $mysqli->connect_error ) {
    die( 'Connect Error: ' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ': ' . $mysqli->connect_error );
}

// insert our data
$sql = "INSERT INTO table1 ( name, email ) VALUES ('{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['name'])}', '{$mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email'])}' )";
$insert = $mysqli->query($sql);

// print response from MySQL
if ( $insert ) {
    echo "Success! Row ID: {$mysqli->insert_id}";
} else {
    die("Error: {$mysqli->errno} : {$mysqli->error}");
}

// close our connection
$mysqli->close();
}

?> 

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
    <input name="name" type="text">
    <input name="email" type="email">
    <input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>

Display each name and email here like:

<div class="name">Get Name Here from Database</div><div class="email">Get Email Here from Database</div>
```

The code above works on posting but I want to make it like, whenever I go to same page it must display that data rom database below the form.

Comment: Since you are a newbie and you are learning, my advice would be to learn about prepared statements to prevent SQL injection. Now you are vulnerable (at least you are using mysqli api). Regarding your question: what is wrong with doing a select query and displaying results? You can find tons of tutorials on google if you don't know how to

Answer (score 0):

Try to use binds variables and prepared statements:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "db");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
  exit();
}

if (isset($_POST['scriptname'])) {
  $scriptname = $_POST['scriptname'];

  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO appslist(listall) VALUES (?)");
  $stmt->bind_param('s', $scriptname);

  /* execute prepared statement */
  $stmt->execute();

  printf("%d Row inserted.\n", $stmt->affected_rows);

  /* close statement and connection */
  $stmt->close();
 }
?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
   Script Name: <input type="text" name="scriptname">
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Ouput:

```
1 Row inserted.
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: i get this error `Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\newpost\index.php on line 20`

Comment: this is line 20 `$stmt->bind_param('s',$scriptname);`

Comment: dear, can you please make a simple code for me only to insert into database from that input on my question. that above is not my code and i don't know much in php but i know it's not that complicated to make onl simple code to insert from one single input into database

Comment: i would really appreciate it

Comment: but what this meanss i don't get it `appslist` ?

Comment: but you didn't make your post with my form isn't ?

Comment: @MmPp, I have edited the post and I have added how to insert using the form, I have tested it and it works properly, have a look to the code again.

Comment: i have updated my question dear and posted new cod that worked for me can you please read the whole question

Comment: @MmPp, my last comment, after insert , use a "select" sentence in order to retrieve data from database, after that, iterate it and display it in the div tag

Comment: @rescobar i agree that OP should use prepared statements. But he is asking how to list all the records from the table under the form.